# Tic-Tac-Toe in Javascript - Changing Players

Tags: javascript

I am completely new to coding and I've been working on a 2-player Tic-Tac-Toe project. I am having  an issue where I can't get the game to change the player. I'm trying to change the turn by multiply by -1 and it hasn't worked. Can anyone offer any insight as to how to change turn via that method?

Javascript

```
/*---------------------------- Variables (state) ----------------------------*/

let whoseTurn, winner, board

/*------------------------ Cached Element References ------------------------*/


const squares = document.querySelectorAll(".square")
const gameStatus = document.querySelector("#message")

/*----------------------------- Event Listeners -----------------------------*/

for(let i = 0; i <squares.length; i++){
  squares[i].addEventListener("click", handleClick)
}

/*-------------------------------- Functions --------------------------------*/

init()

function handleClick(event) {
  if (whoseTurn === 1){
    event.target.innerText = "X"
    gameStatus.innerHTML = "It's Player X's turn"
    board[event.target.id] = 1
  } else {
    event.target.innerText = "O"
    gameStatus.innerHTML = "It's Player O's turn"
    board[event.target.id] = -1
  }
}

function init() {
  whoseTurn = 1
  winner = null
  board = ["", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""]
  render()
    }

 function render() {
   for (let i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
     const selectedSq = board[i];
     if(selectedSq.innerText === "X") {
       board[i] = 1
     } else if(selectedSq.innerText === "O") {
       board[i] = -1
     } else {
       board[i] = null
     }
   }
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not changing in any part of the code the turn of the user. Basically I recreated with your code the following:

- Setting the first message to `It's Player X's turn` because it is the first player to play
- Added the mechanism to swap the user after a click

The swap was done easily on the function `handleClick`. You don't need to multiply or do crazy stuff if you swap the variable `whosTurn` that will solve it.

```
function handleClick(event) {
  if (whoseTurn === 1) {
    event.target.innerText = "X"
    gameStatus.innerHTML = "It's Player O's turn"
    board[event.target.id] = 1
    // when the user X clicks, it needs to swap to -1 so O can play
    whoseTurn = -1;
  } else {
    event.target.innerText = "O"
    gameStatus.innerHTML = "It's Player X's turn"
    board[event.target.id] = -1
    // when the user O clicks, it needs to swap to 1 so X can play
    whoseTurn = 1;
  }
}
```

Here is the code working as expected, although the mechanism to check if a player wins is your task ;)

```js
/*---------------------------- Variables (state) ----------------------------*/

let whoseTurn, winner, board;

/*------------------------ Cached Element References ------------------------*/


const squares = document.querySelectorAll(".square");
const gameStatus = document.querySelector("#message");

/*----------------------------- Event Listeners -----------------------------*/

for (let i = 0; i < squares.length; i++) {
  squares[i].addEventListener("click", handleClick);
}

/*-------------------------------- Functions --------------------------------*/

init()

function handleClick(event) {
  if (whoseTurn === 1) {
    event.target.innerText = "X"
    gameStatus.innerHTML = "It's Player O's turn"
    board[event.target.id] = 1
    whoseTurn = -1;
  } else {
    event.target.innerText = "O"
    gameStatus.innerHTML = "It's Player X's turn"
    board[event.target.id] = -1
    whoseTurn = 1;
  }
}

function init() {
  gameStatus.innerHTML = "It's Player X's turn"
  whoseTurn = 1
  winner = null
  board = ["", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""]
  render()
}

function render() {
  for (let i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
    const selectedSq = board[i];
    if (selectedSq.innerText === "X") {
      board[i] = 1
    } else if (selectedSq.innerText === "O") {
      board[i] = -1
    } else {
      board[i] = null
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.square {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div id="message"> Message </div>
<div style="display: flex;">
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
</div>
<div style="display: flex;">
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
</div>
<div style="display: flex;">
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
</div>
```